# Self-intersection of sum of Eff cone generators on Picard rank 2 surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $S$ be a smooth, projective, complex surface with Picard rank 2, whose effective cone is generated by two curves of negative self-intersection, $C_1$ and $C_2$ (i.e. $C_1^2<0$ and $C_2^2<0$). In this situation, what is known about $(C_1+C_2)^2$? In particular, is it ever true that $(C_1+C_2)^2<0$?

Comment: What is an example of a surface whose effective cone has this property?

Comment: @DanielLoughran: What about a double cover of $\mathbf P^2$ branched over a smooth sextic with exactly one tritangent line (and no other everywhere-tangent curves)?

Comment: By the way, I think one might be able to get examples with $(C_1+C_1)^2<0$ in the following way. (I don't have time to work out the details now, but maybe someone else can, or explain why this fails.) Start with any surface $S$ satisfying your hypotheses such that $C_1$ and $C_2$ intersect transversely. Then for any natural number $a$ we can construct a smooth surface $S'$ with a line bundle $L$ and a finite cover $\pi: S' \rightarrow S$ such that $\pi^* C_2 = L^a$. Then $\pi^* C_1 + L$ is equal (in $Pic \otimes \mathbf Q$) to $\pi^* (C_1 + (1/a) \, C_2)$. For sufficiently large $a$ we have...

Comment: $(C_1+(1/a) C_2)^2<0$, and $\pi^*$ just.multiplies the intersection numbers by $d^2$ (where $d$ is the degree of $\pi$.) I guess one needs to worry about a) why $S'$ still has Picard number 2, and b) why $L$ has a section. See Lazarsfeld PAG I Section 4.1.B for the construction of these covers.